# Install jQuery 2.2.4 typings for TypeScript 1.8

Tags: jquery, typescript, typescript-typings

I've set up Angular 2 (RC4) with angular-cli and use `typings@0.8.1`.

I installed jQuery with

`npm install jquery@2.2.4 --save`

> adds `"jquery": "^2.2.4"` in package.json

and typings with

`typings install dt~jquery --global --save`

> adds `"jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160704162008"` in typings.json (Note: This typing is for 1.x and 2.x releases!)

When I now use `import $ from 'jquery'` or `import * as $ from 'jquery'` in any of my TypeScript files, the tsc returns:

> [ts] Cannot find module 'jquery'.

Can anybody tell me why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't relate to your question, but are you sure you need jQuery with Angular2? It doesn't work well together.

Comment: Yes, I need one external dependency which relies on jQuery. That's bad, but in the ng2 universum there are currently not much projects which I can use. But thanks to mention that here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you istalled jQuery DefinitelyTyped?

http://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

Comment: Yes, but I've used typings directly which will include them in my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it without rocket science, just do it the old way. Seems that RC4 having some trouble resolving typings correctly. But as I'm a software dev and all the angular related "RC stuff" is changing a lot over the last time, it's hard to solve this for any RC, so I decided to do it a bit old school like:

```
declare var $: any;                 // <-- yep, that's it
declare var FlipClock: any;         // <-- same here

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './template.html',
  styleUrls: ['./styles.css']
})

export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('flipclock') flipClock: ElementRef;
  errors: any;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.flipClock.nativeElement).FlipClock({  // <-- we must make sure that
      clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock'           //     at runtime $ and FlipClock
                                                 //     exists
    });
  }
}
```

To provide jQuery and FlipClock at runtime, we just have to append the scripts in our `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My ng2-rc4 app</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/flipclock/compiled/flipclock.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading ...</my-app>

    <script src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/flipclock/compiled/flipclock.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```